# TextInputLayout setError method throws ClassCastException in 24.2.0

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

I updated support lib version to 24.2.0 and my registration screen is dead now. The problem is in the TextInputLayout, I have two methods:

```
    protected void setError(@Nullable CharSequence errorMsg, @NonNull EditText editText, boolean forceClean) {
        TextInputLayout viewParent = (TextInputLayout) editText.getParent();
        if (forceClean) {
            viewParent.setErrorEnabled(false);
            viewParent.setError(null);
        }
        viewParent.setErrorEnabled(true);
        viewParent.setError(errorMsg);
    }

    protected void clearError(@NonNull EditText editText) {
        TextInputLayout viewParent = (TextInputLayout) editText.getParent();
        viewParent.setErrorEnabled(false);
        viewParent.setError(null);
    }
```

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to cast the parent of EditText to TextInputLayout, in the layout I have this kind of code for that:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
          android:id="@+id/login_registration_firstname"
          style="@style/registration_form_field"
          android:hint="@string/login_registration_firstname"
          android:inputType="textCapWords" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

So, this worked perfectly fine, but now it throws ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

I'm wondering if there some new guides on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem investigation showed that there is extra layout for some reason, so now we have TextInputLayout -> FrameLayout -> TextInputEditText and that is sad :( so as temp workaround I've created following method:

```
@Nullable
private TextInputLayout getTextInputLayout(@NonNull EditText editText) {
        View currentView = editText;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            ViewParent parent = currentView.getParent();
            if (parent instanceof TextInputLayout) {
                return (TextInputLayout) parent;
            } else {
                currentView = (View) parent;
            }
        }
        return null;
}
```

This one will find your TextInputLayout in view hierarchy.

If you the lucky one you will notice this pink error color change, the easy way to overcome it is override style, in styles.xml:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Design.Error" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption" tools:override="true">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I wonder, why does a thing as simple as this needs a workaround?

Comment: @Shaishav I thought that this is kinda anti-pattern - they always said that hierarchy should be flat, and this one adds two extra levels, at the very beginning EditText was responsible for that - only one view.

Comment: I don't think that it could be a good solution. Android support libraries team can change it everytime, and also you are navigating in the view hierarchy with a cycle and testing each view if is an instanceof.  Just use the InputTextLayout as parameter.

Comment: The solution itself is not the best, but it takes into consideration that they will remove extra ViewGroup on the next release and this code will work.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with this and I ended up using that library -> [MaterialEditTest](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText) who was far more reliable and offers more features.

With that one, you don't need to nest elements and you can modify small label color and error message...

Comment: I'm not considering this as a solution of the problem, but it seems that I will end up with the lib, Design Lib devs changes their mind too fast :) upvoted!

Comment: But you can add the library locally to avoid any further modification from them. Or just specify the version of the library you want to use as *static*

Answer (score 0):

You can check the code of the `TextInputLayout` v24.2.x.
Now it works with a `FrameLayout`.

```
public TextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    // Can't call through to super(Context, AttributeSet, int) since it doesn't exist on API 10
    super(context, attrs);
    //...
    mInputFrame = new FrameLayout(context);
    mInputFrame.setAddStatesFromChildren(true);
    addView(mInputFrame);

    //....

}

@Override
public void addView(View child, int index, final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    if (child instanceof EditText) {
        mInputFrame.addView(child, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(params));
        //...
     } else {
        // Carry on adding the View...
        super.addView(child, index, params);
    }
}
```

where `mInputFrame` is a `FrameLayout`.

It is the reason of your issue (the parent is a `FrameLayout`).

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

You should use the `TextInputLayout` as parameter instead of navigating in the view hierarchy.

Comment: You probably didn't read the question, because you didn't understand the problem. Of course you can find TextInputLayout by id and set the error there, but the point is that you have EditText and you need to set Error.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin You don't need the EditText to set the error. You need just the InputTexLayout. You are only using the the editText to get the parent view. Just use a method protected void clearError(@NonNull InputTextLayout) { ....}

Comment: Maybe my English is bad, I don't have an id of TextInputLayout, only reference of EditText. If you go through the code you will find that I'm already using methods of TextInputLayout.

Comment: OK, but just add an id to your InputTextLayout to be able to call methods on this view. Reading your code you just have to call setError() on this view.